# Unknown error 0x800A01A8 when trying to edit xsl file via TCL (tcom)

Tags: excel, com, tcl

What I am trying to do is to add a text to some excel file, using TCL script . 
For working with excel I am using Tcom .

```
set excelFilePath "C:/TCL.Marko.xlsx"

proc start_tcom {} {
    global excelFilePath excelApp workbook 
    set excelApp [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
    set workbooks [$excelApp Workbooks]
    set workbook [$workbooks Open [file nativename [file join [pwd] $excelFilePath] ] ]
    set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
    #
    set excel_sheet Marko.xlsx
    set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
    set cells [$worksheet Cells]
    return $cells
}
```

Up till this point all works.

```
509 % start_tcom
::tcom::handle0x0284F9D8
```

Then I am running:

```
513 % foreach row {1 2 3} {
    foreach column {A B C} {
        $cells Item $row $column [incr i]
    }
}
```

and getting this error:

```
0x800a01a8 {Unknown error 0x800A01A8}
```

if I am doing 
`save_and_close_tcom`
I can see file Marko.xslx is updated with the correct time and date, so the TCL see the correct file, but still getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563406/301832 looks like it has some bearing, at least on the meaning of the error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "  set excel_sheet Marko.xlsx" should be removed . 
this command means working with tab name "Marko.xlsx" , but this tab doesnt exist. and thats why the error came. 
this is the correct code with explanations :

proc start_tcom {} {

```
            global excelFilePath excelApp workbook 
              set excelApp [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
             # Connect to Excel COM object.

            set workbooks [$excelApp Workbooks]
            set workbook [$workbooks Open [file nativename [file join [pwd] $excelFilePath] ] ]
            set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
            # Create inital workbook.


           set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
         $worksheet Name "Booleans"
  # Rename the first tab.

            set cells [$worksheet Cells]
            return $cells
            #Making cells ready for input
```

}

## Now we ready to work directly with the XSL document

## I’ll show an example of copying a simple txt file in to the XSL we just created .

## Lets assume we have a TXT document named WTX.txt with a list of values.

set fp [open "[pwd]/TEMP/WTX.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp]

## Now as we know each cell in XSL is indexed by a column and raw , so in order to populate the XSL we need to specify the exact indexes.

```
            set Col A 
            set Row 1
```

## in the following code we’re creating a simple while loop to run over the txt file values and populate the XSL with them .

```
            set Row 1
            while {[lindex $file_data $i] != ""} {
            $cells Item $Row $Col $numeric_value_from_file
            incr Row
```

}

## lets discuss the marked line , this is the actual command to populate the cell with the value.

## The actual format of the line is  :  $cells (we created it previously) ITEM (the cell it self)  Row Col

## So what we actually saying is (backwords) Take the Value and put it to cell indexed with some Row and Col.

## EOF.